# How do i make the text fall underneath image when using flexbox?

Tags: html, css

[image]

How to I make the text to fall underneath the image. I know that if you use dispaly:inline-block you could use float:left or float:right. But I'm new to using flexbox is there someone that has more knowledge of this and could help me solve this.

```css
big-row {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.head-text {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 29px;
}

.p-text {
  font-size: 1.25em;
  line-height: 29px;
  margin: 2px;
}

.big-text {
  text-align: left;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 40px;
  width: 50%;
  color: #888;
}

.big-img {
  padding-right: 50px;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.big-img img {
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="big-row">
  <div class="wow fadeInLeft big-text">
    <h1 class="head-text"> Alla tjänster </h1>
    <p class="p-text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce imperdiet luctus nunc, sed ornare velit accumsan id. Cras sit amet justo et velit bibendum elementum ac vel odio. Fusce tortor risus, rhoncus in ultricies ut, rutrum id leo. Pellentesque
      sed venenatis ipsum. Quisque at lacus eu tortor vehicula vestibulum. Aliquam scelerisque tempor elit eu venenatis. In convallis diam quis varius blandit. Vestibulum consectetur ullamcorper urna vel sagittis. Sed malesuada tortor metus, ut porttitor
      odio tristique vel.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="wow pulse big-img">
    <img src="/assets/image/hejhopp.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: read about `order`

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you mean the text to fall under the image? Which text? All of it? Can you not just reorder your html and put the image first? @TemaniAfif is correct to a degree but if not all the text, `order` won't work here as your image and text (title and paragraph) are peers

Comment: I have uploaded an image of how it looks. As you see the text on the left side. When i resize browser it just goes straight down but i want it to go below the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You place the image container before the text container in DOM and give it `float: right`:

```css
.big-row {
  margin-top: 20px;
  line-height: 29px;
}
.big-row, .big-row  > * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.head-text {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.p-text {
  font-size: 1.25em;
  line-height: 29px;
  margin: 2px;
}

.big-text {
  padding-left: 40px;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  color: #888;
  text-align: justify;
}

.big-img {
  padding-right: 50px;
  width: calc(50% + 80px);
  padding: 0 40px;
  float: right;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.big-img img {
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="big-row">
  <div class="wow pulse big-img">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/640x360">
  </div>
  <div class="wow fadeInLeft big-text">
    <h1 class="head-text"> Alla tjänster </h1>
    <p class="p-text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce imperdiet luctus nunc, sed ornare velit accumsan id. Cras sit amet justo et velit bibendum elementum ac vel odio. Fusce tortor risus, rhoncus in ultricies ut, rutrum id leo. Pellentesque
      sed venenatis ipsum. Quisque at lacus eu tortor vehicula vestibulum. Aliquam scelerisque tempor elit eu venenatis. In convallis diam quis varius blandit. Vestibulum consectetur ullamcorper urna vel sagittis. Sed malesuada tortor metus, ut porttitor
      odio tristique vel.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Note you can't obtain this effect with flexbox. Floating is part of CSS Box Model Module.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="big-row">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
 <div class="wow pulse big-img">
    <img src="asset.PNG">
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="wow fadeInLeft big-text">
    <h1 class="head-text"> Alla tjänster </h1>
    <p class="p-text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce imperdiet luctus nunc, sed ornare velit accumsan id. Cras sit amet justo et velit bibendum elementum ac vel odio. Fusce tortor risus, rhoncus in ultricies ut, rutrum id leo. Pellentesque
      sed venenatis ipsum. Quisque at lacus eu tortor vehicula vestibulum. Aliquam scelerisque tempor elit eu venenatis. In convallis diam quis varius blandit. Vestibulum consectetur ullamcorper urna vel sagittis. Sed malesuada tortor metus, ut porttitor
      odio tristique vel.</p>
  </div></div>
 </div></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```